# Get username by user ID aspnet.Identity in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

With the least effort how to find out Username in Asp.Net MVC

try following code and seems like not working

```
 string Username = User.Identity.GetUserName(Id);
```

Comment: Do you want get current user name? or user name by ID?

Comment: No I dont want current logged user's user name

Answer (score 14):

You need get user user information from user manager:

```
string username = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()
    .GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(ID).UserName;
```

Comment: how to assign this value to string variable

Comment: This is a string variable actually. You could write `string username=...` instead

Comment: @Chathz `var` automatically determines the type of the variable by what's being assigned to it, so in this case, `username` would be of type `string`.

Answer (score 7):

you can get the username of any MembershipUser using the below code:

```
string userName = Membership.GetUser(userId).UserName;
```

`userId` is the Guid primary key of the user.

Comment: but here I getting following error `An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The provider user key supplied is invalid.  It must be of type System.Guid`

Comment: @Chathz so make sure the userId you are using is a GUID. Use a cast if necessary. What is the value of the ID you are using?

Comment: @Chathz the problem isn't with my code, the problem is how you are getting the value of the UserId. This answers your question as you asked it.

Comment: why I'm getting error as `Unable to connect to SQL Server database.` when I using follwing code `string duser = Membership.GetUser(userID).UserName;`

Comment: is that becuse my membership providers diffrent ? I'm using aspnet.identity membership provider for my project

Comment: @Chathz check your connection strings to make sure the details are correct.  But that problem has nothing to do with retrieving a user's details, and should be asked as a separate question if you can't fix it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
        //first get the User id by calling user.idetntity
        var user = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        //appuser
        ApplicationUser appUser = new ApplicationUser();
        appUser = db.Users.Find(user);

        //get the user name
        var Name= appUser.UserName;
```

Comment: Do explain your answer a bit, rather than just writing down some code, it helps the readers to understand your answer better.